# Getting a TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple) error in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I'm new to classes in Python and I'm trying to print this Square object. However, I keep getting an error that is saying TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type tuple). Tells me to check line 29 and 32.

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, lenSide, color):
        self.lenSide = lenSide
        self.color = color
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.lenSide, self.color
    def getSide(self, lenSide):
        return lenSide
    def getArea(self, lenSide):  # return area
        print(lenSide + lenSide)
    def getPerm(self, lenSide):  # return perimeter
        print(self.lenSide*4)
    def setColor(self, color):  # return color
        self.color = color
    def describe(self, color, lenSide):
        print("I am a " + self.color + " square with side" + self.lenSide)
def mySquare():
    newSquare = Square(5, "red")
    print(newSquare)
mySquare()
```

Comment: `return self.lenSide, self.color` is returning a tuple, but `__repr__` must return a string (in most contexts). What's your intent there? Did you mean `return str(self.lenSide) + self.color` to concatenate them? What's your expected output?

Comment: [What is the difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr) may be of assistance.

Comment: Hi! Yes I am meaning to concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.

The `__repr__` special method is meant to return a string. Instead of returning a string, you returned a tuple `(self.lenSide, self.color)`. To convert the tuple to an string, you can use `str()`. So the `__repr__` method should return `str((self.lenSide, self.color))` (note the extra parentases to form an tuple).

See also:
[What is the difference between **str** and **repr**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the goal of the **repr** method is to "return the object representation in string format." Currently your implementation is returning a tuple.

All you have to do is modify **repr** to something like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Length:' + str(self.lenSide) + ' ' + 'Color:' + self.color
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`__repr()__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

> Called by the repr() built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. **The return value must be a string object.**

[**`__str()__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

> Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. **The return value must be a string object.**

So you have to return a string object and not a non-string (in this case a tuple)

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.lenSide) + ' ' + str(self.color)
```